# Mock groovy script using spock

Tags: gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, spock

I have the following script files
**aScript.groovy** and **bScript.groovy** both are in vars folder, these scripts will be called from a **jenkinsFile**  in the project folder

**aScript.groovy**

```
def call(){
  return bScript()
}
```

**bScript.groovy**

```
def call(){
  return "bar"
}
```

I am using gradle for build my **build.gradle** file look as follows

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/groovy']
        }
        output.resourcesDir = "build/resources/test/lib/commons@master/vars"
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src/test/groovy']
        }
        output.resourcesDir = "build/resources/test"
    }
}
sourceSets.main.resources { srcDirs = ['vars', 'src/main/resources', 'resources'] }
sourceSets.test.resources { srcDirs = ['src/test/resources'] }
dependencies {

    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.9'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4'
    testCompile 'com.lesfurets:jenkins-pipeline-unit:1.0'
    testCompile 'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.2.2'
    testCompile 'org.objenesis:objenesis:1.2'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:3.4.1'

    compile ('org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core:2.46.3'){
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'log4j-over-slf4j'
    }

    compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.21'
    compile 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.ivy', name:'ivy', version:'2.2.0'

}
```

**Test Classes**

```
class aScriptSpec extends Specification {

    /**
     * Delegate to the test helper
     */
    @Delegate JenkinsPipelineTestHelper pipelineTestHelper

    def setup() {
        pipelineTestHelper = new JenkinsPipelineTestHelper()
        pipelineTestHelper.setUp()
        pipelineTestHelper.setJobVariables()
        def library = library().name('commons')
                .defaultVersion("master")
                .allowOverride(true)
                .implicit(false)
                .targetPath(sharedLibs)
                .retriever(localSource(sharedLibs))
                .build()
        helper.registerSharedLibrary(library)

        helper.registerAllowedMethod('timestamps', [Closure.class], null)
        helper.registerAllowedMethod('node', [Closure.class], null)
        helper.registerAllowedMethod("stage", [String.class], null)
    }

    def "pipeline test"() {

        given:
            addEnvVar('workerLabel','testworker')
            addEnvVar('BRANCH_NAME','PRbuild')

            //to mock bScript
            helper.registerAllowedMethod("bScript", [], null)//1. tried using registerAllowedMethod

            bScript.metaClass.static.call = {return 'bar'} //2. tried using metaClass

            binding.setVariable('bScript', new Object() { //3. tried using metaClass
                def call() {
                    println "bScript call mocked"
                }
            })


        when:

            loadScript('Jenkinsfile')
        then:
            printCallStack()
    }
}


class JenkinsPipelineTestHelper extends BasePipelineTest{

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder()

    String sharedLibs = this.class.getResource('/lib').getFile()
    void setUp() throws Exception {

        scriptRoots += 'vars'
        super.setUp()
    }
    /**
     * Variables that Jenkins expects
     */
    void setJobVariables() {...}



    void addEnvVar(String name, String val) {...}


}
```

**my project structure**

```
   app
      \--build
             \--classes
                      \--test
                             \--aScriptSpec.class
             \--resources
                      \--test
                             \--lib
                                   \--commons@master

 \--vars                                                                                   
   \-- aScript.groovy                                                                                 
   |--bScript.groovy
|--src/test/groovy
               \--aScriptSpec.groovy
|--vars
       \--aScript.groovy
       |--bScript.groovy
|--build.gradle
\--Jenkinsfile
```

I need to test **aScript** functionality so i want to mock **bscript()** i tried using `bScript.metaClass.static.call = {return 'bar'}` its giving me `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: bScript for class: aScriptSpec`

how can i mock bScript()?

Comment: Could you post your test code?

Comment: added the test code

Comment: Jenkins file has `@Library('commons@master')_      aScript() `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe aScript.groovy and bScript.groovy should in var[s] not in var folder.

```
   .
   └── vars
       ├── aScript.groovy
       └── bScript.groovy
```

Then code bellow works like a charm if you want to mock bScript

```
 helper.registerAllowedMethod("bScript", [], { return 'foo'})
```

UPD:

I've just reproduced that.

I think it doesn't as the first time you mock a method like:

```
 helper.registerAllowedMethod("bScript", [], {'foo'})
```

or whatever this particular object appears in the groovyClassPath

When you call

```
   def script = loadScript("template/pipeline/template.groovy")
```

to load your pipeline at this point classPath is updated again with the object defined in your lib. So I suppose your mock is overwritten.

So the workaround here is to wrap the pipeline body in a method, like someMethod :

```
   @Library("commons")
   import java.io.File // or whatever

   echo aScript() // this is not mocked

   def someMethod() {
      echo aScript()  // this one could be mocked
   }
   return this
```

Then your test could be like:

```
 @Test
 void mock_bscript() throws Exception {
    helper.registerAllowedMethod("bScript", [], {'foo'}) // this one doesn't work
    def script = loadScript("template/pipeline/template.groovy")
    helper.registerAllowedMethod("bScript", [], {'ololo'}) // this does
    script.someMethod()
    printCallStack()
 }
```

So the call stack would be

```
  Loading shared library jenkins-commons with version master
  template.run()
       template.aScript()
          aScript.bScript()
       template.echo(bar)
  template.someMethod()
      template.aScript()
         aScript.bScript()
      template.echo(ololo)
```

Comment: i think gradle is not able to identify it after build , not sure how to resolve it